# Text doesn't allow mouseover animation (Inkscape)

Tags: animation, svg, text, inkscape

Good evening,

I have a problem with text inside my rect. I have set an animation to start when you mouseover the rectangle, so that it would become orange. The animation works great, but it is disrupted when the mouse hovers over the text inside it. Is there a way to make the text "not selectable" in order to let the animation work?

Thanks in advance for any help.

P.s: I'm providing the code of the file i am working on.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="744.09448819"
   height="1052.3622047"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.5 r10040"
   sodipodi:docname="Nuovo documento 1">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.7"
     inkscape:cx="361.92867"
     inkscape:cy="655.61451"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="true"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="705"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1">
    <inkscape:grid
       type="xygrid"
       id="grid2985" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Livello 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <rect
       style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
       id="testrect"
       width="320"
       height="100"
       x="60"
       y="232.36218"
       ry="14.285714" />
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:40px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Sans"
       x="73.173828"
       y="296.68835"
       id="randomtext"
       sodipodi:linespacing="125%"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan2991"
         x="73.173828"
         y="296.68835">RANDOM TEXT</tspan></text>
  </g>
  <animate
     id="testrect_anim1"
     attributeName="fill"
     xlink:href="#testrect"
     begin="mouseover"
     from="#ffffff"
     to="#ff6600"
     dur="0.2s"
     fill="freeze" />
  <animate
     id="testrect_anim2"
     attributeName="fill"
     xlink:href="#testrect"
     begin="mouseout"
     from="#ff6600"
     to="#ffffff"
     dur="0.2s"
     fill="freeze" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Why not just add the animation to the text as well?

Answer (score 3):

Include `pointer-events="none"` to the text element.

```
<text
   xml:space="preserve"
   style="font-size:40px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Sans"
   x="73.173828"
   y="296.68835"
   id="randomtext"
   sodipodi:linespacing="125%">
   <tspan>
     sodipodi:role="line"
     id="tspan2991"
     pointer-events="none"
     x="73.173828"
     y="296.68835">RANDOM TEXT
   </tspan>
</text>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Francis Hemsher, works like a charm for me!